# How to delete a no longer used custom bin table?

Tags: database

I'm testing the [cacheAPI](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/cache) with a custom bin. Everything is working. On the other hand, while testing, I created a custom bin with a name that does not suit me.

```
cache.lorem_bin:
  class: Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface
  tags:
    - { name: cache.bin }
  factory: ['@cache_factory', 'get']
  arguments: [lorem_bin]
```

A table in DB `cache_lorem_bin` was created.

So I modified it and another table was created with the name of this new custom bin. But the old table `cache_lorem_bin` was not deleted even after clearing the cache. I don't see in the documentation how to delete this table. It's not blocking but I would like to know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache bin tables are automatically removed when you uninstall the module. You should have uninstalled the module before making the change and after that install the module again.

However, as a developer you can choose to drop the table manually to avoid the  reinstall process. The new cache bin table will be created the first time it is used.

Comment: Uninstalling the module did not delete the tables. I deleted them manually as you told me and everything is ok. I had quite a few and it's much cleaner.

Comment: You have to uninstall the old version before the change. It only deletes tables that are still defined in code.

Comment: Thank you, indeed, that's right and it makes sense.